# dataframe backfill with max value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO6oK.png)

I want to backfill each item where date_activity is *1/1/2000  12:00:00* with the max date_activity for each item_id. In the end, I want something like this using pandas
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gUvF.png)

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create missing values by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and then backfilling values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                   'date_active':pd.date_range('2019-02-02', periods=7)})
print (df)
   item_id date_active
0        1  2019-02-02
1        1  2019-02-03
2        1  2019-02-04
3        2  2019-02-05
4        2  2019-02-06
5        2  2019-02-07
6        2  2019-02-08

df['date_active'] = df['date_active'].mask(df['item_id'].duplicated(keep='last')).bfill()
print (df)
   item_id date_active
0        1  2019-02-04
1        1  2019-02-04
2        1  2019-02-04
3        2  2019-02-08
4        2  2019-02-08
5        2  2019-02-08
6        2  2019-02-08
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['item_id'].duplicated(keep='last'))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
Name: item_id, dtype: bool

print (df['date_active'].mask(df['item_id'].duplicated(keep='last')))

0          NaT
1          NaT
2   2019-02-04
3          NaT
4          NaT
5          NaT
6   2019-02-08
Name: date_active, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

EDIT:

If real data is necessary sorting values before solution for last maximum value per group:

```
print (df)
   item_id      date_active
0        1  7/26/2019 17:06
1        1  8/27/2019 17:06

df['date_active'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_active'])
df = df.sort_values(['item_id','date_active'])
df['date_active'] = df['date_active'].mask(df['item_id'].duplicated(keep='last')).bfill()
print (df)
   item_id         date_active
0        1 2019-08-27 17:06:00
1        1 2019-08-27 17:06:00
```

EDIT1: Use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) for add missing datetimes per groups:

```
df['date_active'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_active'])
df = df.sort_values(['item_id','date_active'])

df = (df.set_index('date_active').groupby('item_id')
        .resample('D')
        .last()
        .drop('item_id', axis=1)
        .reset_index())
df['date_active'] = df['date_active'].mask(df['item_id'].duplicated(keep='last')).bfill()
print (df.tail())
    item_id date_active
28        1  2019-08-27
29        1  2019-08-27
30        1  2019-08-27
31        1  2019-08-27
32        1  2019-08-27
```

Comment: this is interesting, how would you go about creating missing values if your start date was say  2019-02-04 and the current date your end date?

Comment: you have a date 2019-02-04 and 2019-04-03, you want to get the dates between the two and into whatever dataframe column these dates are logged. How would you go about that?